# UNIFIED StageStyle and Transparent Scene produce black background instead of transparent

Tags: css, javafx

JavaFX 8 has StageStyle.Unified, enabling to create OS X  style, unified toolbars. I have tested the following code works correctly in JDK 8u5.(the scene background is transparent and the button appears against the stage background.)

However in JDK 8u25 and JDK 8u31 there is a weird behavior. the scene background becomes black.
changing the scene color to anything other than transparent works fine, it displays that color.

It is looking like a bug to me unless I am missing something,
Any ideas?

```
public class UnifiedTest extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    StackPane testPane = new StackPane();
    testPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color:transparent;");

    Label someText = new Label("TEXT AGAINST TRANSPARENT SCENE");
    testPane.getChildren().add(someText);

    Scene myScene = new Scene(testPane,500,500);
    myScene.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);



    primaryStage.setScene(myScene);
    primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNIFIED);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Application");
    primaryStage.show();
}


/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

Some more information:

By stage background I meant the background of the window that is provided by the OS.

I am trying to create a unified toolbar. According to JavaFX 8 API the way to do it is to use StageStyle.UNIFIED. this will give a window provided by the OSX.

It looks like this when there is no scene added: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObLHa.png

However when I setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT) the scene background becomes black:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObLHa.png#2

The desired result is to see the text against the background of the first link. It worked with JDK 8u5, but now I am using 8u31 and instead of that grey I get black. What is weird is that if I setFill(Color.RED) the background becomes red as expected

From the JavaFX 8 api:
public static final StageStyle UNIFIED
Defines a Stage style with platform decorations and eliminates the border between client area and decorations. The client area background is unified with the decorations. This is a conditional feature, to check if it is supported see Platform.isSupported(javafx.application.ConditionalFeature). If the feature is not supported by the platform, this style downgrades to StageStyle.DECORATED
` NOTE: To see the effect the Scene covering the Stage should have Color.TRANSPARENT

Comment: What does this mean: "the scene background is transparent and the button appears against the stage background"?  There is no background property for stage in JavaFX, what is the "stage background"?  Can you supply screen shots of the 8u5 and 8u31 windows?  You can upload them to http://imgur.com if you don't have enough reputation on StackOverflow to include images in your question.

Comment: Great, that helps a lot.  Looks like a broken feature to me.  Log a bug report against the runtime project at: https://javafx-jira.kenai.com.

Comment: thank you very much for checking it out. I was scratching my head wether I am missing something..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is a bug, which is fixed for Java 8u60:

- [JDK-8095040 StageStyle.UNIFIED not working on OSX 10.9.5](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8095040)

Kevin Rushforth comments on the bug tracker:

> It looks like the regression was introduced some time in 8u20.

Comment: Looks like the bug exists again (Win7 with 8u92 and 8u112)